# How to run hadoop multithread way in single JVM?

Tags: hadoop, jvm, mapreduce

I have 4 core desktop and want to use all my cores for local data processing with hadoop.
(i.e. sometimes I have enough power to process data locally sometimes I submit same jobs to cluster).

By default hadoop local mode runs only one mapper and one reducer so my local jobs are really slow.
I do not want to setup cluster on single machine first because of "painful" configuration and second I have to create jar each time. So perfect solution is to how run embedded Hadoop on a single machine

PS pseudo-distributed mode is bad option since it will create cluster with Single node, so I will get only one mapper and I have to spend some time on additional configuration.

Comment: I think you want pseudo-distributed mode.  The easiest way to do it on Windows is to download the Cloudera Hadoop demo: https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/Downloads?gclid=CKLR7Nv0wrICFQz0nAod7g8AZQ

Comment: No, "pseudo-distributed mode" will run cluster with single node and 2 JVM. So results will be the same 1 mapper and 1 reducer

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [MultithreadedMapRunner](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultithreadedMapRunner.html) - just set up it in JobConf's setMapRunnerClass method and don't forget to set mapred.map.multithreadedrunner.threads to desirable concurrency level.

Also there is an another way, you should:

- set [MultithreadedMapper](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/map/MultithreadedMapper.html) as your mapper class in Job-typed object
- call `MultithreadedMapper.setMapperClass` with you actual mapper class
- call `MultithreadedMapper.setNumberOfThreads` with desirable concurrency level

But be careful, your mapper class should be thread safe and it's setup and cleanup methods would be called several times, so it isn't a smart idea to mix MultithreadedMapper with MultipulOutput, unless you implement you own MultithreadedMapper inspired class.

Comment: Sorry for long reply, yes MultithreadedMapper works with hadoop 1.0.3, but I deceived you, you shouldn't extend it, here is a full multithreaded word count example - https://github.com/rystsov/learning-hadoop/blob/master/src/main/java/com/twitter/rystsov/mr/MultithreadedWordCount.java

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop purposely does not run more than one task at the same time in one JVM for isolation purposes. And in stand-alone (local) mode, only one JVM is ever used. If you want to make use of your four cores, you should run in pseudo-distributed mode, and increase the max number of concurrent tasks to four. You can do this with the `mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` and `mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum` properties.

Comment: Actually I can, using conf.set("mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks", "4") for running several mapper in one JVM. But this dosn't work for local mode.

Comment: mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks will run multiple tasks sequentially in the same JVM, not as separate threads. Again, you can't have multiple Map tasks running concurrently in the same JVM, unless you specifically write the threading code yourself, or, like rystsov suggested, use a map task specifically for this. Why do you want it anyway? Multiple JVMs should be almost as fast.

Comment: I relly like Cascading Local mode it is really fast locally. But I can support compatibility to run my code both on hadoop and local mode. So  I want to run my simple data process scipts which can be efficiently run on hadoop and locally, since almost half I can do in memory(I have 16GB RAM on laptop).

Answer (score 0):

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    Job job = new Job(conf, "SolerRandomHit");

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);

    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);


    job.setMapperClass(MultithreadedMapper.class);
```