# Map/Reduce wall-time not sensitive to the number of Reduce tasks

Tags: java, performance, hadoop, join, mapreduce

I wrote a simple Map/Reduce program in Java for the relational join operation for two text files. The algorithm is as described in many places, that doing the join in the Reduce tasks.

I want to tune it to have better performance. The first thing is to try different number of Reduce tasks. For now I only run in a single computer with 4-core, but really in distributed file system.

I meet the strange phenomenon, is that, the wall-time (time stat till time finish) is even a little longer if I run 4, or 32 reduce tasks, than the time that I run only 1 reduce task:

```
1 reducer:  22.4 seconds
4 reducer:  23.3 seconds
32 reducer:  26.1 seconds
```

By looking at this trend, I can not really explain. The first impression is that the bottleneck would be in the I/O, because I am running in a single machine, the high I/O operation is not really paralleled. However by looking at the CPU stat, the i/o wait time is very small (and the input data is only several Mega bytes in my test data), so it does not look like a good explanation.

One thing to mention is that I monitor the CPU usage of different cores while running the map/reduce program, and I found most of the time the CPU usage is limited to one core, and does not look like in paralleled very much.

I also suspect that the benefit of running more reducers is eliminated by the extra of the map/reduce overhead.

What do you think about this?

[Update] I found out the statement (also proved by some timing observation) that in single JVM, the map and reduce task only runs in serial but not multi-threaded.  That will explain why the results are more time with more reducer tasks.

I see the multi-threaded mapper is supported by Hadoop using the MultithreadedMapper class, and I tried, unfortunately the result becomes once again even a little worse.

But I don't know why there is a class called MultithreadedMapper, but why there is another like MultithreadedReducer?

Comment: Are you sure this can be answered without your code ?

Comment: I can post the code here sure. Just feel that it is a general question but specific to my codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this question, I think I found the answer. Hadoop does not try to run mapper and reducer in multi-threads at all, when I run it in a Stand-alone mode. This perfectly explain my finding in the timings.

On the other hand, I see articles and posts saying that running in Pseduo mode will enable running concurrently (or multi-processes more exactly).
I tried but have some problem there. However I think this is a new question so this question may be said answered.

Answer (score 1):

Number of reducers should be configured depending upon the available reduce task slots. Time taken by application is greater for 4/32 reducers is because:
1) Machine is 4 core, so ideal number of reducers should be around 2.
2) Input data is very small, so time taken in initializing reduce tasks is more than the parallel processing.

For better benchmark on the same hardware, test application with reducers as 1,2 and at most 3. Also, use some heavier data set (at least few blocks i.e. 512 MB to 1 GB).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will try. But before that, I found out some statement that running map/reduce in a single JVM actually will not run multi-threaded. as shown in this post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504690/how-to-run-hadoop-multithread-way-in-single-jvm)

Comment: The post you are referring is for local mode installation. But I am assuming you are using Pseudo distributed mode.

Comment: No I am not using Pseudo distributed mode. I saw people saying only Pseudo mode is multi-threaded, is it right?

Comment: I finished configuring Pseudo distributed mode, and use hadoop shell script to run the program towards the file in local DHFS. However it looks like nothing change in clock-time.

Comment: I post the issue of setting the maximum tasks in Pseudo mode in another question. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33130749/hadoop-setting-maxium-simultaneous-map-reduce-task-does-not-work-in-psedue-mode)